# Grey out text in a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a toolbox object that is like a listbox but each individual item can have a different font colour? I'm trying to make a mod manager of sorts and want to grey out the text for those mods that are uninstalled.

[image: 1]

Comment: Forms listboxes can do owner-draw.

Comment: Please as one question at a time (I removed the other one).

Comment: DataGridView with one visible column and varying cell styles?

Comment: Flow or table layout panel with button or link label bank?

Comment: Though tbh, why not chuck those two list box away and just have a single datagridview with a normal column for the mod name and a checkbox column for whether the mod is installed or not?

Comment: "Grey out" typically means "disabled" which in turn implies an object of some sot is used and in some cases the `Enabled` property is false.  If you put such objects in the  `ListBox`  items collection and/or use `DataBonding` you can use `OwnerDraw` to paint them as desired.  If the items are just strings, you dont really have enough data on hand to do that.  You do now have enough new terms to do meaningful research.

Comment: Thanks you lot, I didn't know a datagridview was a thing, also why I added multiple questions was because I was at my question limit apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(listBox1.Items[e.Index]), new Font("Aerial", 8), Brushes.Gray, new Point(0, 0));
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

For this to work, change the DrawMode of the Listbox to OwnerDrawFixed.

Also, if you want to select an item in a combobox, try something like this:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```